# Visual Studio 2010: Invalid Pointer when deleting project configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a Visual Studio 2010 C++ solution with two projects: an executable and a library. I am successfully able to delete project configurations from Configuration Manager for one of the projects (executable), but not the other (library).

Both projects were previously part of a vs2008 solution that have since been upgraded to vs2010.

When I try to delete a configuration from the library project, I get the error:

> The operation could not be completed. Invalid pointer.

This happens for all configurations for that project.

Since this happens with only one of the projects, it leads me to believe that there is probably something wrong with the project and that's why VS2010 doesn't like it. Any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't be asking myself what was wrong, I'd be deleting from the .sln and/or vcxprojs in notepad. If I really needed to know what was wrong, I'd start deleting _everything else_ bit by bit until I found it, and it wouldn't be the first time I'd done it either. It's basically a bisect operation, so it won't take long.

Comment: @zeromus yup, that's what I ended up doing indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found that the problem was with some left-over project configuration in the library project file (`library.vcxproj`). The offending section was:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
  <VisualStudio>
    <UserProperties RESOURCE_FILE="library.rc" />
  </VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

After deleting the section above from the project file and reloading the solution, I was able to delete project configurations.